# Native namespace exported in C++/CLI project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am wrapping a native C++ library for consumption by the CLR. However, I'm running into a strange... problem?

The native library's headers look like so:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar();

        //etc...

    };
}
```

So, to consume this class, I have my own class definition:

```
#include "Foo/Bar.h"

namespace FooNet {
    public ref class Bar {
    private:
        Foo::Bar * m_Impl;

    internal:
        Bar(Foo::Bar *);

        //etc...

    };
}
```

And, that all works great. However, when I reference the resulting assembly into a C# project (for example) and look at the object browser, I notice that it contains <strike>not</strike> only my CLR classes (`FooNet::Bar`)<strike>, but also the native classes (`Foo::Bar`) too</strike>!

<strike>I'm not particularly enthusiastic about exposing the native classes, since they use pointers and `std::string`s and other .NET unfriendly stuff, so is there any way to stop this from happening?</strike>

Edit: Things I learned today:

1. The object browser shows all namespaces in the solution, not in just whatever project you happen to be looking at.
2. Native C++ classes are **not** exposed in managed assemblies.

Comment: Are your object browser settings set to show internal classes?  The native classes shouldn't be marked as public by the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the native classes are listed in the metadata for the benefit of managed debuggers, but they should be marked `internal` and not usable by consumer code.

Comment: Oh wow I feel stupid. The test project was part of the same solution as the C++/CLI library, and so of course it showed both.